Detection of type of Ethernet connection
Trying to understand if a company can detect the difference between Ethernet connection to a router versus an xfinity pod with an Ethernet port. I am being offered a position with the stipulation to be ‘hard wired’ at first I thought oh Ethernet from my pod in my office will do but the more I think about it, I don’t want to breach any contract if this will show up.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No, not without some guesswork on their part. That requirement is usually because wireless connections often cause very slow connections to services like a VPN. No one is going to fire you over it, but don't complain to their IT when everything is slow. Those pods are pretty unreliable in my experience, but might be fine for what you need

Thank you!! I found it a little odd but I know due to speeds being an issue/concerns for data breaches etc but I didn’t have any issue using WiFi with my last healthcare VPN. Thanks again!!

The issue may not be technical but compliance oriented, and if it is, say, required by HIPPA or some similar compliance regime,  they may be very serious about it.  Someone who does not have a vantage point within your network cannot tell how you connect within your LAN, but an observer inside your network (like for instance software on your work device) can.

The real problem may be much simpler, for example: The corporate laptop has WIFI disabled, hence they require the laptop to be hard wired.

The simplest solution here is just to reach out to the company tell them your situation - you use a wifi-extender to avoid running wires round your house - however there is a port free in your office that you can use to plug the computer into.
Ask them if that is acceptable - if so great.
If not, tell them that you don't want to run additional wires round your house, are there any company approved devices/solutions that they can suggest to solve the problem - for example a Powerline Networking Adapter.
Worst case say that you could get a contractor in to run new ethernet round your house and would the company cover the cost for that?
In short I don't see a reason to hide this from the company - I doubt that the IT group has the power to prevent your hiring if you operate above board by describing the actual problem to be solved to them.
